# How to link to the HD version of a vimeo video

Tags: vimeo, fancybox-2

I am playing my vimeo video in a fancy box using the link

https://vimeo.com/513... Howeverthey show up in the non HD version . I have to click HD to view them.

How do i link to the  HD version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from [Vimeo's FAQ](http://vimeo.com/help/faq/embedding#default_hd)

> Plus and PRO users have the option to not only embed their videos in
>   HD, but also to default those videos to be viewed in HD. This is a
>   sweet way to make sure that your crisp HD videos are seen in their
>   full resolution glory when they're embedded off of Vimeo.
>
> If you'd like all of your videos to default to HD, just go to your
>   account settings and select the "Videos" tab. Under "What about source
>   files, mobile, and HD embedding?" select "Always play my videos in HD,
>   when possible" and then click the "Save as default" button. Check
>   "Also, apply to existing videos" to do just that.
>
> Otherwise, if you have a specific video you want to default to HD mode
>   click the "Settings" button that appears below the video on your video
>   clip page and then select the "Embed" tab. Check the box next to
>   "Default this video to HD quality when embedded" and click the "Save
>   Changes" button.

It seems you have to be a Plus or a PRO user. If you are, there should be settings you can control at the account settings page.